# Node-RED Handle error from node that throws no standardexception

Tags: error-handling, node-red, pushover

I want to use the Pushover Node to send notifications. I'm already using it via curl for some time and very seldom some messages aren't sent. Thats why I have in bash

```
echo "$curlOutput" | grep -qP '{"status":1' 
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ] 
then
    echo "$2" | mail --append "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" -s "$1" name@company.com
fi
```

to capture the error and then send the message via email.

Now I want to do something similiar in Node-Red. For testing purposes if simulated a network error via `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 104.20.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "Pushovertest" -j REJECT`

That successfully blocks. In node-red-log I see

> 18 May 13:46:24 - [error] [pushover:252a17dc.1239d8] Error: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 104.20.125.71:443

Now look at this Node-RED flow

[image: Node-RED flow]

The error is displayed in the debug window and comes from pushover node. The catch node doesn't catch the expection, obviously because pushover doesn't use the exception framework https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/nodered-exception-handling-framework/

First test passed: There is an error logged. But how can I react to this error within Node-RED to do something else in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess from looking at the source that the error is coming from line [103](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/blob/master/social/pushover/57-pushover.js#L103)
of the `57-pushover.js` file.

The call to `node.error()` on this line is not pushing the incoming `msg` object so it won't be passed to the catch node. There are 2 signatures for the `node.error()` function, the first just takes the error message, the second takes the error message and the incoming `msg` object, only the second forwards the error and `msg` object is passed to the catch node.

Please feel free to submit a pull request to update this node.